# Stripe with ajax so the user is not redirected to another page

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, stripe-payments

I have a multistep form, in the step 3 there is a button "Pay" that when is clicked it shows a Stripe modal using the jQuery below:

```
  <form action="{{ route('registration.charge') }}" method="post" id="paymentForm">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" id="stripeToken"/>
            <input type="submit" href="" id="payment" class="btn btn-primary float-right"
                   value="Pay"/>
        </form>
```

Charge method to handle the Stripe charge:

```
public function charge(Request $request)
    {
        Stripe::setApiKey(config('services.stripe.secret'));
        $source = $request->stripeToken;
        Charge::create([
            'currency' => 'eur',
            'description' => 'Example charge',
            'amount' => 2500,
            'source' => $source,
        ]);
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/charge', [
    'uses' => 'RegistrationController@charge',
    'as'   => 'registration.charge'
]);
```

When the user clicks in pay the stripe modal appears the user fills the form and click in Pay button the Stripe validates and send the token and the user is redirected to another page (http://proj.test/charge) because of the `charge()`.

Do you know how to instead of redirecting the user to (http://proj.test/charge) change Stripe code to use Ajax so the user remains on the same page? So that is possible to show in that some page a success message, for example, informing that the payment was completed.

Stripe code:

```
let stripe = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: "{{config('services.stripe.key')}}",
    image: "",
    locale: "auto",
    token: (token) => {
        document.getElementById('stripeToken').value = token.id;
        document.getElementById('paymentForm').submit();
    }
});

document.getElementById('payment').addEventListener('click', function(e){

    stripe.open({
        name: 'test',
        description: 'test',
        amount: 1000
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Like this is not working, it appears the "   console.log("Ajax Error!");" and then the user is redirected to "http://proj.test/charge".

```
let stripe = StripeCheckout.configure({
        key: "{{config('services.stripe.key')}}",
        image: "",
        locale: "auto",
        token: (token) => {
            document.querySelector('#stripeToken').value = token.id;
            document.querySelector('#paymentForm').submit();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '{{route('conferences.charge')}}',
                data: {tokenid: token.id, email: token.email},
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data == 'success') {
                        console.log("success");
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("error");
                       console.log("Ajax Error!");

                    }

                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }); 
        }
    });
    document.getElementById('payment').addEventListener('click', function(e){

        stripe.open({
            name: 'test',
            description: 'test',
            amount: '{{session('total')}}'
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

RegistrationController returning code 200:

```
public function charge(Request $request)
    {
        Stripe::setApiKey(config('services.stripe.secret'));

        $source = $request->stripeToken;

        $selectedRtypes =  Session::get('selectedRtypes');

        $amount = (collect($selectedRtypes)->first()['total']) * 100;

        try{
            Charge::create([
                'currency' => 'eur',
                'description' => 'Example charge',
                'amount' => $amount,
                'source' => $source,
            ]);
        }
        catch(\Exception $e){
            return response()->json(['status' => $e->getMessage()], 422);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'success',
        ], 200);


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this could probably be achieved in different ways.

Here is a solution from a VUE script that uses jquery to get the form

```
send: function () {
  Stripe.setPublishableKey("stripekey")
  const $form = $('#payment-form')
  Stripe.card.createToken($form, (status, response) => {
    if (response.error) {
      return
    }

    this.payment_token = response.id
    this.post('<your controller charge>', this.getFormData())
   })
},
post: function (url, data) {
    axios.post(url, data).then(response => {
    // handle success here
    }).catch(error => {
    // handle error here
    })
},
getFormData: function () {
  return {
    'payment_token': this.payment_token
  }
},
```

But what I think you are looking for is

```
send: function () {      
 Stripe.setPublishableKey("stripekey")
  const $form = $('#payment-form')

  Stripe.card.createToken($form, (status, response) => {
    if (response.error) {
      return
    }

    let stripeToken = response.id
  })
}
```

This uses the stripe javascript sdk

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I update the question using jquery ajax. But it's not working, the user is redirected to another page "http://proj.test/charge".

Comment: That would be impossible with ajax if it is not built into the success code. You are probably submitting the form some way.

Comment: Thanks, removing this "        document.getElementById('paymentForm').submit();
" now the user is not redirected to another page. But its not working, on the console appears "jquery.min.js:4 POST http://proj.test/charge 419 (unknown status)".

Comment: Return a response(200) if charge succeeds from your charge controller. Also check your log there might be some other problem with the code